# Using square brackets for packet header in scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I have a question related to the data we get when use square brackets in scapy.

Reference code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from scapy.all import *

def spoof_pkt(pkt):
    a = pkt[IP]

pkt = sniff(filter='tcp',prn=spoof_pkt)
```

The above code tries to sniff tcp packet. My question is that when I use a syntax like `pkt[IP]` in scapy, do I get just the IP header, or do I get the entire packet starting from the IP header ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the entire packet including and following the IP header:

```
>>> a = Ether()/IP()/ICMP()
>>> a[IP]
<IP  frag=0 proto=icmp |<ICMP  |>>
```

If you wanted only the IP layer, you would have to remove its payload:

```
>>> c = a.copy()[IP]
>>> c.remove_payload()
>>> c
<IP  |>
```

Note that a packet and all its sub fields are mutable